# Isomorphism between Dual Spaces and Annihilators in a Direct Sum

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vector-space-isomorphism

Let $U$ be a finite dimensional vector space and the direct sum of two subspaces $V$ and $W$: $$U=V \oplus W$$ Give an explicit isomorphism that verifies:
$$1) V^* \cong W^0$$
$$2) U^* \cong V^0 \oplus W^0$$
This is easy to prove using $\dim U = n$ , but that does not give me any clue to finding the actual isomorphism. I tried using a base for $U$ and splitting it into two bases for $V$ and $W$, but then, every functional I try to define in $V^*$ goes to zero in $W^0$. As for part 2) I have no idea on how to start. Maybe it can be proven using 1). Any suggestions?

Comment: Don't you want every functional in $V^*$ to vanish on $W$?  Or are you saying that your map takes every functional in $V^*$ to the zero functional in $U^*$?  For part (1) you could try the map $V^*\to U^*$ which extends each functional on $V$ to a functional on $U$ by vanishing on $W$.  Explicitly, a map $f\colon V\to\mathbf{R}$ would become the map $U\to\mathbf{R}$ given by $(v,w)\mapsto (f(v),0)$.

Comment: ^That looks good, the image of the map Austin defines is precisely the annihilator of W, and it is easy to check that it is injective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Austin's suggestion works well for 1, for two consider:
$$
\Phi: U^* \to V^0 \oplus W^0
$$
which sends the map $f \to f_v+f_w$ i.e since $U=V \oplus W$, we have $f(u)=f(v+w)$ (unique representation) and $f(v+w)=f(v)+f(w):=f_v(v)+f_w(w)$, by definition $f_v$ vanishes on $W$ and hence is in $W^0$, and $f_w$ vanishes on $V$ and is in $V^0$. You also should probably check that $V^0$ and $W^0$ are disjoint, so the direct sum is well-defined in the first place.